# Are possible ones these MIPS instructions?

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

I'm trying to crash problems in the book 'Computer organization and Design'.

I come across a sequence of instructions in solution of book.
But Qtspim, mips assembler, can't interpret them.
Here is instructions. (book 4th edition, problem 2.14.4 a)

```
add  $t2, $t0, $0
srl  $t2, $t2, 11
and  $t2, $t2, 0x0000003f
and  $t1, $t1, 0xffffffc0
ori  $t1, $t1, $t2
```

Why ori has 3 registers? (I thought it is not r-type instruction)
Why and has 32bit immediate? (I thought instruction itself has 32bit wise.)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two instructions look ok, but the following three do not. It's possible that those are typos, or that the author of the book was using a different MIPS assembler which accepts those instructions and converts them into valid ones.

For example:

```
and $t2,$t2,0x0000003f
```

=>
    `lui $t2,0  ; ANDing the upper halfword with 0x0000 would set it to 0`
    `andi $t2,$t2,0x003f`

---

```
and $t1,$t1,0xffffffc0
```

=>
    `andi $t1,$t1,0xffc0  ; ANDing the upper halfword with 0xffff would not change it`

---

```
ori $t1,$t1,$t2
```

=>
    `or $t1,$t1,$t2`